# Bash not recognizing packages installed using pip-3.6

Tags: terminal, bash, python, macports

I installed `pip-3.6` using Mac Ports:

```
sudo port install py36-pip
```

Then, using this version of `pip`, I installed `virtualenv`:

```
sudo pip-3.6 install virtualenv
```

Now when I tried using `virtualenv`, `bash` isn't recognizing it.

**PS:** I didn't want to select `pip-3.6` as `pip` because I have pip working with OS X's version of Python 2.7.

Comment: I would install virtualenv using macports - using two package managers always gets confusing

Answer (score -1):

MacPorts may not have put things where you think, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183112/installing-pip-for-python3-3). Did the pip-3.6 command work? What do you get when you `which pip-3.6`?

Have you considered Homebrew over MacPorts? pip3 comes automagically with python3.x with Homebrew. It also has a virtualenv package that is easy enough to uninstall if needed.

Comment: pip-3.6 did work and successfully installed virtualenv